# easiest way to batch setup many constant

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I'm new to R.

I have around 50~100 universal constant to set up in my R script.

These constants are lag, rate of decay, power transformation, model parameter etc.

Later I'll iterate through these parameters to fit the best model for some data.

something like:

```
data1.transformation1.lag1 <- 1
data1.transformation1.lag2 <- 2
data1.transformation1.lag3 <- 3

data1.transformation2.lag1 <- 1
data1.transformation3.lag2 <- 2
data1.transformation4.lag3 <- 3

...

data1.model1.parameter1 <- .3
data1.model1.parameter2 <- .4
data1.model1.parameter3 <- .7

data1.model2.parameter1 <- 0
data1.model2.parameter2 <- .3
data1.model2.parameter3 <- .9

data2.model1.parameter1 <- .5
data2.model1.parameter2 <- 1
data2.model1.parameter3 <- 1.2

...
```

What is the best practice and easiest way to set up these constant?

(To avoid typing many times and easier to read)

Comment: If all the constants have same value can you use the same constant everywhere?

Comment: It's not the same value, I'm just making an example.
The numbers are arbitrary numeric float number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating lot of variables in the global environment I would suggest you to use a list or dataframe to store them.

```
ref_list <- setNames(as.list(c(1:3, .4, .9, 4:1)), 
                             c(paste0('data1.transformation1.lag', 1:3), 
                               paste0('data1.model1.parameter', 1:2), 
                               paste0('data2.model1.parameter', 1:4)))
```

You can access any value that you want using `$` sign.

```
ref_list$data2.model1.parameter1
#[1] 4
ref_list$data1.model1.parameter1
#[1] 0.4
```

If you still need these variables in global environment for some other reason use `list2env`.

```
list2env(ref_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: You are right. 

Probably I should create a class of some sort?

 But yours is easier to visualize if I were to print all the numbers in a sheet

Comment: Yes, keeping all these constants in a list/dataframe makes them easier to manage.